# Convert jpeg values in txt file to image

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm trying in this code to convert jpeg values in txt file to jpg image.
The size of captured image = 120*160 and the numbers of values in file = 2396 (I don't know why this total length).

I get this error

```
na = np.array(pixels, dtype=np.uint8).reshape((int(h),int(w)))
  ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2396 into shape (120,160)
```

Code:

```
# Open image file, slurp the lot
contents = Path('C://Users//hp//Desktop//file.txt').read_text()

# Make a list of anything that looks like numbers using a regex...
# ... taking first as height, second as width and remainder as pixels
h, w, *pixels = re.findall(r'[0-9]+', contents)

# Now make pixels into Numpy array of uint8 and reshape to correct height, width and depth
na = np.array(pixels, dtype=np.uint8).reshape((int(h),int(w)))

# Now make the Numpy array into a PIL Image and save
Image.fromarray(na).save('C://Users//hp//Desktop//jp.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for the PIL library. You already have a JPEG file.
Just convert those numbers to bytes and save them.

```
with open("C://Users//hp//Desktop//file.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()
data = data.split(",") # split the numbers
data = [int(b) for b in data] # convert them to integers
data = data[2:] # remove width and height
data = bytes(data) # convert the array of numbers to bytes
with open("C://Users//hp//Desktop//jp.jpg", "wb") as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Result:

[image: jp.jpg]

Note: There appears to be missing data at the end. You might have not captured all the data.
You claim to have 2396 values, but your example has 3842.

Comment: thanks a lot! I have Q, please ,i'm new in image processing I need to know why you convert to byte? firstly I think that the each value in file(like 255,123, ..) represent byte?

Comment: Because Python needs a bytes object to write it to a file. A list could could contain values that aren't trivially converted to bytes.